# ACF Checkbox loop not displaying all posts

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a shortcode that displays a loop, in which it SHOULD display all posts in 'products', that have the checkbox selected as value 'yes'. However, it's not displaying all the posts, it's only displaying one.

Here's my code:

```html
function featured_products() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'home_featured',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
        ),
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $output = '<p>' . get_the_title() . '</p>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        $output = "<p>There aren't any products to display.</p>";
    }
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('featured_products', 'featured_products');
```

What am I doing wrong here in terms of displaying more than one post?

This is what my custom field setup looks like:

[image]

Now I'm having trouble with the output. For some reason, the loop is displaying right at the top of the page's content container:

```html
function featured_products() {
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'home_featured',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),
);
$output .= '<div class="products">';
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $output .= '<div class="col-eq-height col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:30px;">';
        $output .= '<div class="product">';
        $output .= '<div id="thumbnail"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';
        $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail();
        $output .= '</a></div>';
        $output .= '<div id="content">';
        $output .= '<p id="title"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>';
        echo '<p>' . the_field('product_price_exc_vat') . '</p>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    $output .= "<p>There aren't any products to display.</p>";
}
$output .= '</div>';
return $output;
}
add_shortcode('featured_products', 'featured_products');
```

Comment: might need to change 'compare' => '=', is it a true/false field?

Comment: also - there is no beginning of the ul -

Comment: lastly - you are overwriting the output everytime, so it will only take the last post

Comment: to gather the output - out a dot infront of it - like this : $output .= "whatever"; - And initiate $output outside the loop like this : $output = "";

Comment: it is most likely just a matter of putting a dot  in it, so it collects all data, instead of overwriting it

Comment: and either throwing the </ul> out, or pushing it into $output as well - you shouldn't echo and return

Comment: Perfect man, adding the dots did it for me. Thanks man. I updated my answer with an image on how I set up the field, anyway. FYI. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that $output is being overwritten every time it iterates.

Meaning that you will only get the last title.

putting a dot infront of the = sign, will gather it instead of overwriting it.

So to sum up -

Initiate

```
$output ="";
```

Outside the loop, and then push it together inside your while

```
$output .="whateverHtml".$variable."whateverHtml";
```

Comment: @JakePunton  
use get_the_title() instead of the_title() - reason : the_title() echoes out as soon as it is read - not for use in shortcodes etc. - I think that is the reason

Comment: That works, but even using the get_field(); ACF function isn't working. So the WP functions do, but the ACF won't load the values from the custom fields.

Comment: you should definetly still use get_field() - if it for some reason won't find it - try to give the post id, as a second parameter, like this : get_field('product_price_exc_vat', get_the_ID()); and it should still be a part of $output

Comment: $output .= '<p>' . get_field('product_price_exc_vat', get_the_ID()) . '</p>'; Isn't working mate.

Comment: Can't see why that shouldn't work, I've done similar things myself before? 
Only reason I can think of, is that it hasn't been set? or the ID is wrong? I guess you can print get_post_meta(get_the_ID()); to see all of your meta values for the post.

Comment: It might be valid, to create a new question, as to why you can't access your acf values inside functions.php, - this question was about the checkbox and loop :) - you might need to get new people in here, and the original question has been answered.